# Update failed - table doesn't exist

Tags: updating, database

I'm running a D7 core update and all but one database updates pass. The one that doesn't pass gives me the following error message:

`Failed: DatabaseSchemaObjectDoesNotExistException: Cannot add field erg_field_data_field_carousel_slide_url.field_carousel_slide_url: table doesn't exist. in DatabaseSchema_mysql->addField() (line 325 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_site/includes/database/mysql/schema.inc).`

I tried running a registry-rebuild, but I still get that error when I ran the update again.

I do have a table in my database called `erg_field_data_field_carousel_slide_url`. Why would the update be looking for the same table name, but with part of it repeated and appended? And is there any fix?

EDIT: So turns out there was an update for the Bootstrap Carousel module, of course. I'm new to running regular updates, so can anyone provide helpful information about what in `schema.inc` actually causes this behavior?

Comment: I have no idea, try disabling and uninstalling carousel then updating core and installing carousel after.

Comment: What is the size of your db ? I know in your db this table might be exist but in spite of that you will getting error.